# How to create a channel from another with transducers?

Tags: clojure, core.async, transducer

I want to create a channel of `clojure.core.async` from another one that just filters specific messages. Therefore I found a function called filter<.

```
=> (def c1 (chan))
=> (def c2 (filter< even? c1))
=> (put! c1 1)
=> (put! c1 2)
=> (<!! c2)
2
```

But the function and its friends are marked as deprecated:

> Deprecated - this function will be removed. Use transducer instead

There are some ways to use channels with transducer like `chan` with the `xform` parameter. How can I build a new channel from an existing one using transducers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some research on this, found a couple of interesting articles ([first](http://blog.eikeland.se/2014/08/14/transducers/) and [second](https://malcolmsparks.com/posts/transducers.html)), and then got something working using [`pipeline`](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/pipeline)

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as async :refer [chan <!! pipeline put!]])
(def c1 (chan))
(def c2 (chan))

(pipeline 4 c2 (filter even?) c1)

(put! c1 1)
(put! c1 2)
(<!! c2)
;;=> 2
```

The second article I linked makes this a bit cleaner with some helper functions around the pipeline function:

```
(defn ncpus []
  (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)))

(defn parallelism []
  (+ (ncpus) 1))

(defn add-transducer
  [in xf]
  (let [out (chan (buffer 16))]
    (pipeline (parallelism) out xf in)
    out))
```

Then you can simply tie channels together with

```
(def c1 (chan))
(def c2 (add-transducer c1 (filter even?))
```

To complete the answer, as you found yourself you can use pipe in a similar fashion:

```
(defn pipe-trans
  [ci xf]
  (let [co (chan 1 xf)]
    (pipe ci co)
    co))
(def c1 (chan))
(def c2 (pipe-trans c1 (filter even?)))
```

Comment: Inspired by you I created a facory method using `pipe`.

    (defn from-chan [ci xf]
      (let [co (chan 1 xf)]
        (pipe ci co)
        co))

Comment: nice, glad I could help.

Comment: i've added a version of your factory method to try and complete the answer in case others search for it.

Comment: Noticed this: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC-153
Seems like pipe-trans could be simplified to (defn pipe-trans [ci xf] (pipe ci (chan 1 xf))) but it's undocumented